# Cakephp never ending request

Tags: php, cakephp, apache2, php-5.3, cakephp-2.2

I'm quite new to cakephp and trying to debug a code from someone else.
The problem is I get a never ending request, despite the fact that both view and crontroller seem to run properly. I even tryed to add an exit; in both of them or even introduce a syntax error in the controller, the request never ends and the browser keeps trying to load the page endlessly.

Here is the code of the controller :

```
    public function categories()
{
    file_put_contents("/tmp/logfile.log",time()." categories bla\n", FILE_APPEND);
    $catData = $this->SpecificKeywordCategorie->find('all');
    $modelnameLessValues = array();
    foreach($catData as $singleCat)
    {
        $modelnameLessValues[] = $singleCat['SpecificKeywordCategorie'];
    }
    $this->set('categories',$modelnameLessValues);
    file_put_contents("/tmp/logfile.log",time()." categories end blu\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

and the view code "categories.ctp :

```
    <?php
    file_put_contents("/tmp/logfile.log","view json ".json_encode($categories),FILE_APPEND);
    print(json_encode($categories));
    file_put_contents("/tmp/logfile.log","view json before exit",FILE_APPEND);
    exit;
    ?>
```

all the file_put_contents entries are written in the logfile. but the exit seems to be ignored and if I do a request in a browser it never ends...

Same thing happens if I add a syntax error on controller or view. (of course, in this case, log entries are not written)

I know nothing about cakephp internals, but php scripts running outside it are running well on same apache instance.

Any idea where to look to find where this infinite request comes from ?

We are running cakephp 2.2.3

Comment: I think the infinite loop is comes because there might be many SpecificKeywordCategorie data so the loop might not end easily. How many is the data?

Comment: By "never ending request" does it mean the page never finishes loading, or does it mean that the page is getting loaded over and over?

Comment: It means it never finishes loading. Well, we solved the problem. We added some log trace in cakephp core and everything went back to normal. Then we removed the log trace and it was still working. So I think it was more related about something wrong on our server than on cakephp